# No consigo que despues del if entre en las demas condiciones

Tags: python, linux, condiciones, python-requests, audio

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ast import If
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import os
import time
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import pytz
import subprocess
from gtts import gTTS
import playsound
```

Aquí es donde declaro todas las consignas de activación del robot para darle el tipo de palabra que tiene que reconocer el palabra y que la coteje con la que dice el usuario.

```
###Consignas de activación
ACTIVATION = "kaixo robot"
MOVEMENT1 ="circulo"
MOVEMENT2 ="cuadrado"
MOVEMENT3 ="linea"
```

Aquí es donde declaro todas las consignas de respuesta del programa una vez cotejadas con la palabras que dice el usuario son las que debe usar.

```
##Respuestas del robot
ESCUCHANDO = 'escuchando'
READY = "estoy listo"
MOV_1 = "movimiento 1"
MOV_2 = "movimiento 2"
MOV_3 = "movimiento 3"

IDIOMA = 'es'

RESPUESTA_1  = gTTS(text=ESCUCHANDO, lang=IDIOMA, slow=False)
RESPUESTA_2  = gTTS(text=READY, lang=IDIOMA, slow=False)
RESPUESTA_3  = gTTS(text=MOV_1, lang=IDIOMA, slow=False)
RESPUESTA_4  = gTTS(text=MOV_2, lang=IDIOMA, slow=False)
RESPUESTA_5  = gTTS(text=MOV_3, lang=IDIOMA, slow=False)
```

Función que se encarga de reconocer el audio y analizarlo para después dar una respuesta al usuario.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def get_audio():
   r = sr.Recognizer()
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
       r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
       audio = r.listen(source)
       said = ""

       try:
           said = r.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")
           print(said)
       except Exception as e:
           print("Exception: " + str(e))

   return said.lower()
```

Se guardan las respuestas en formato mp3

```
RESPUESTA_1.save("respuesta_1.mp3")
RESPUESTA_2.save("respuesta_2.mp3")
RESPUESTA_3.save("respuesta_3.mp3")
RESPUESTA_4.save("respuesta_4.mp3")
RESPUESTA_5.save("respuesta_5.mp3")
```

Aquí esta el problema en cuestión. Quiero que una vez se reconozca la "hotword" entre en los ifs que según la orden que le des haga un movimiento u otro. Consigo que reconozca la frase y se meta en las condiciones. Pero luego ya no sigue y la verdad que no se me ocurre como hacerlo. Ya que parece que se queda estancado.

```
while True:
   
   playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_1.mp3")
   print("Listening")
   text = get_audio()

   if text.count(ACTIVATION) > 0:
       

       playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_2.mp3")
       print("I am ready")
       text = get_audio()
                           

       if text.count(MOVEMENT1) > 0:
           playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_3.mp3")
           print("Movimiento_1")
           text = get_audio()
                   
       if text.count(MOVEMENT2) > 0:
           playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_4.mp3")
           print("Movimiento_2")
           text = get_audio()

       if text.count(MOVEMENT3) > 0:
           playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_5.mp3")
           print("Movimiento_3")
           text = get_audio()
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que se queda estancado? ¿No salen las trazas de las diferentes llamadas a `get_audio`? ¿Tienen esas trazas los valores esperados?

Comment: Por otra parte, en `get_audio` no veo que espere a que el usuario diga algo, ¿Qué sucede si el usuario no habla?

Comment: como es la secuencia de instrucciones que le estas dando? lo digo porque segun el codigo, parece que tienes que decir siempre la palabra clave y luego la orden... Tienes varios `text = get_audio()` en cada if, y aparentemente solo deberias necesitar el que hay despues de la palabra clave, no? te plantearia ponerle algun else a los if, a ver si es que no cumple las condiciones.

Comment: @eferion después de la palabra clave, no consigo que entre en los 3 if restantes. Lo he comprado con audios pre grabados para ver si el problema era de la pronunciacion y ni asi

Comment: @HeytalePazguato se queda esperando a detectar sonido, y si no coincide no entra en la función.

Comment: Ok, entonces el problema es, entra en el primer `if` e imprime "I am ready" y luego ya no sucede nada, ¿Es correcto? ¿Podrías agregar `print(text)` después de obtener el audio tras imprimir "I am ready"? De esa forma vas a ver si detecta algo o no

Comment: @HeytalePazguato exacto, eso sucede. Si estuve probando con prints para ver hasta donde llegaba pero no consigo que entre, y eso que dectecta el audio

Answer (score 1):

No sé si he comprendido del todo tu problema, en caso de que quieras ejecutar el primer if y que el resto se ejecute dependiendo del primero tu código está correcto. Si lo que quieres es que se ejecuten los diferentes condicionales independientemente del primero, pon en su lugar else if al mismo nivel, sin indentar.

La sintaxis de la construcción if ... elif ... else ... es la siguiente:

```
if condición_1:
    bloque 1
elif condición_2:
    bloque 2
else:
    bloque 3
```

Si se cumple la condición 1, se ejecuta el bloque 1
Si no se cumple la condición 1 pero sí que se cumple la condición 2, se ejecuta el bloque 2
Si no se cumplen ni la condición 1 ni la condición 2, se ejecuta el bloque 3.
Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Lo que quiero es que una vez entre en el primer if, se ejecuten los 3 if restantes pero no consigo que eso pase

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizar el comando try except

```
try:
  print(x)
except:
  print("An exception occurred")
```

En tu caso intenta con este codigo:

```
try:
   while True:
   
      playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_1.mp3")
      print("Escuchando.......")
      text = get_audio()

      if text.count(ACTIVATION) > 0:
       

          playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_2.mp3")
          print("I am ready")
          text = get_audio()
                           

          if text.count(MOVEMENT1) > 0:
              playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_3.mp3")
              print("Movimiento_1")
              text = get_audio()
                   
          if text.count(MOVEMENT2) > 0:
              playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_4.mp3")
              print("Movimiento_2")
              text = get_audio()

          if text.count(MOVEMENT3) > 0:
              playsound.playsound("/home/ikerlan/Speech/respuesta_5.mp3")
              print("Movimiento_3")
              text = get_audio()
              
except sr.UnknownValueError:
   print("Error desconocido,escuchando ")
```